# Better StackExchange site for this question?

Tags: discussion

There must be a better StackExchange site for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35206/how-to-ask-for-details-to-a-poorly-reviewer no?

Comment: Maybe ux.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I migrated it to ux.stackexchange.com since the primary issue is a user experience issue, not a workplace issue.

None of their moderators were online, hopefully they come here if it was not scoped right.